# Как реализовать правильное движение объекта?

Tags: unity3d

как сделать так что-бы объект двигался непрерывно?
дело в том что если делать толчок единоразово при нажатии клавиши то персонаж медленно остановиться из-за трения. Если его толкать каждую секунду то импульсы будут суммироваться и скорость будет расти. кроме того я не знаю как делать остановку так как я не могу знать текущую скорость чтобы затормозить объект.
Как это обойти?

Comment: я ни разу не разработчик игр, но мне кажется что решение данного вопроса ОЧЕНЬ сильно зависит от механик игры. Хотя в общем виде постепенная остановка безотносительно механик делается с помощью затухающих функций  https://easings.net/

Comment: `так как я не могу знать текущую скорость`  - поясните... Программа же ваша.

Comment: `я не могу знать текущую скорость` У тебя есть Rigidbody, у него есть свойство velocity. velocity = скорость. Устанавливаешь в фиксед апдейте нужную тебе velocity и объект будет двигаться непрерывно. Либо двигай через rigidbody.MovePosition и тогда у тебя будет полный контроль и над скоростью и над перемещением.

Comment: MBo, я использую rb.AddForce и импульс медленно затухал соответственно скорость менялась, поэтому я не знаю точную скорость.

Comment: KOTIK, спасибо, попробую таким способом.

Comment: KOTIK, кинешь пожалуйста ссылку на гайд по velocity. velocity, просто всё что я нашёл ничего дельного как применять не сказали.